# change value of submit button onclick with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm implementing a function where, when a button is clicked, the text of the button is changed which works properly. The button appears only when a condition is true which also works perfectly. But when the button appears when the condition is true when it's clicked the values doesn't change.

```
 <button ng-if ="item.user == 'Login'" class="{{love_default}}" ng-click=" love=!love">{{loveText}}</button>
```

JS

```
$scope.love = true;
$scope.love_default = "button button-small button-positive icon icon-left ion-ios-heart";
$scope.$watch('love', function() {
    $scope.loveText = $scope.love ? 'Login' : 'Already Logged In';
})
```

When i take out the `ng-if` and click on the button it works

```
<button class="{{love_default}}" ng-click=" love=!love">{{loveText}}</button>
```

but i want it working with the `ng-if` applied to the button

Comment: Have you tried using ng-show instead of ng-if?

Comment: Rather than just changing the value of love in the `ng-click` wouldn't it be better to create a `click` method that sets both the value of `love` and the value of `loveText` at the same time avoiding the use of the `watch`?

Comment: ng-show produced the same results